# Cannot post data from React Js to Node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs

I am beginner use React Js and Node Js, I get a problem, I cannot post my data from React Js to Node Js, I have been looking for the way but failed all, I don't know why.

This is my complete code.

This is my react file 'member.js', run on port 3000 (http://localhost:3000/member).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Member extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { player: {} };
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/player', {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          number: 123,
          name: "John",
          position: "Andrew"
        })
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Request failed', error)
    });    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="member-page">
        <form>
          <input type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Member;
```

and this is my node file 'player.js', run on port 4000 (http://localhost:4000/player).

```
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "react_1"
});

app.post('/player', function(req, res, next) {

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
      next();

  var player = req.body;
  var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO player VALUES ?', player, function(err, result) {
    // Neat!
  });
  res.end('Success');
});

app.listen(4000, function() {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 4000!');
});
```

I don't know where I do a mistake, please anyone correct my code either `member.js` or `player.js`.

Thank you very much for all the help.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm suspecting that the problem is that the server is only accepting when CORS is enabled, and in your client your request has no-cors enabled... I'm not an expert at this but I'm trying to help

Comment: What is the error that you see in the console

Comment: Don't set `text/plain` as content type if you're sending JSON data, and make sure that your server is using [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) to parse the posted data.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @robertklep. I think problem is in **var player = req.body;**

Try:

Install **body-parser** npm package

```
npm i -S body-parser
```

Configure **body-parser**

```
   var http = require('http');
   var mysql = require('mysql');
   var express = require('express');
   var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
   var app = express(); 

   app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

   //enable CORS
   app.use(function(req, res, next) {
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
     next();
  });

  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
       host: "localhost",
       user: "root",
       password: "",
       database: "react_1"
  });

  app.post('/player', (req, res) => {
       var player = req.body;
       var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO player VALUES ?', player, (error, results, fields) => {
          if (error) throw error;
          // Neat!
       });
      res.send('Success');
    });

  app.listen(4000, function() {
     console.log('Example app listening on port 4000!');
   });
```

Comment: I have tried your recommendation, but when I tried 'console.log(req.body)', in console show undefined, what's next. .?

Comment: @JohnAndrew I moved CORS related code outside the **/player** route and created a [express middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html). Moreover, I changed `res.end('Success')` to `res.send('Success')` because res.send uses content-type:text/html as Content-Type. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank yo very much @Md Zahidul Islam

Comment: @JohnAndrew I am happy that it help. Would you mind accepting it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
var router = express.Router();
router.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
})); 

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 5000!')
})

app.use('/', router);
```

Try to Configure your node server like this

Comment: I have tried your recommendation, but when I tried 'console.log(req.body)', in console show undefined, what's next. .?

Answer (score 0):

First install body-parser using :

**`npm install body-parser`**

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

If you are passing string data then use

`app.use(bodyParser.text());`

Otherwise if you are passing data as Json then use

`app.use(bodyParser.Json());`

It should work in your case.